# Ionic/Cordova iPhone XS Max Gap/Screen Size Issue

Tags: cordova, ionic3, iphone-xs-max

I thought it was an issue with the splash screen, but I removed all of the splash screen items and just kept the one to be used with the Storyboard image.

```
<splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" width="2732" />
```

I've confirmed the meta viewport HTML time and time again:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

...but yet my app when it launches in the iPhone XS Max still looks like this:

[image: Ionic App on iPhone XS Max with Gap]

Any ideas or similar issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for anyone else who runs into this, I simply deleted all of the various plugins and reinstalled them.  In the previous version to what is out there now in terms of the Ionic and/or Cordova CLI, adding a plugin such as

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-splashscreen --save
```

with the "--save", and then doing an ionic cordova build iOS seemed to do the trick.